# how to write a scope for where conditions in model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following model

```
class Customer
  class CustomerUsage < ActiveRecord::Base

    self.table_name = 'vCustomerDetails'

  end
end
```

How do i write scope for `where vCustomerDetails.State = 'California' and vCustomerDetails.Statusflag = 'Y'` ?

Comment: Why don't you follow Rails conventions? Using uppercase table and column names doesn't allow you to use Rails' magic and will make everything much harder.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly like below, but should belike that.

```
  scope :customers_from_california, -> { where(state: "California") }
  scope :having_status_flag, -> { where(flag: "Y") }
```

you can also join them like,

```
  scope :flagged_californians, ->{customers_from_california.where(flag: "Y")}
```

p.s. i know naming sucks -))

Comment: I am not sure if this will work. It seems like the OP uses uppercase column names.

Comment: @spickermann depends on the adapter used and/or the database itself. I know `sql-server` adapter has an option for `reflect_lowercase_schema` which is handled appropriately (for method naming e.g. ` def State` becomes `def state` when set to `true`) . As for the database I know ms-sql doesn't care about case, mySQL has an option to enable/disable, this feature and I have not come across a time where postgresql cares (can't speak for any others as I haven't used them). @marmeladze maybe change the name to `:flagged_californians` :)

Comment: yeah, that's better -))

Comment: @spickermann i've just shown how it should be written, and assume that the question owner knows how he/she will be able to fix it to work correct way.